# Need help to tweak shell script monitor user

Tags: shell

I need to add where I can pass argument to get a specific user session. If I don't pass argument it return user over 24 hrs. Suppose:

```
./user-mon.sh oracle 18
```

It should show me if user Oracle went over 18 hrs. Anyone can help to achieve this. Where I can make change and

Here is script

```
#!/bin/bash
#monitor user session over 24 hrs

IFS='$NIFS' 

for who in $(who -u); do 
    IFS="$OIFS" 
    #skip any session that is not a try 
    line=$(awk '{print $1, $3, $4}' <<< "$who") 
    If grep  'old' <<< "$line";then
        Continue 
    fi
    echo "user logged in over 24 hours"
    IFS="$NIFS" 
done
```

IFS="$OIFS"

Comment: The 1st script is good only  it's complain about  line 19 read -r -a record < <(grep "^$user" < < (who)) syntax error when I give command line argument  ./user.sh Ali 18.   2nd :  is it  possible  ./user.  The output says " user longged 80 hour. "  Instead it show user name . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and you want to:

1. be able to determine who has been logged in for more than the hours given as an argument; and
2. optionally be able to specify a specific user instead of all, and a number of hours to check against as arguments to your script.

It's more than doable. First, lets correct a nagging error at the beginning of your script. `IFS='$NIFS'` sets `IFS` to a literal `"\$NIFS"` because you have enclosed `'$NIFS'` in *single-quotes* preventing *variable expansion*. That renders your use of `IFS` meaningless. Always surround variables with *double-quotes* to enable normal variable expansion.

To optionally take arguments for your script, you can make use of *parameter expansions* to initialize variables to the values given on the command line (or to default values if no argument is given) using the form:

```
var="${param:-default}"
```

For your script taking a username and number of hours you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="${1:-}"   ## user to check (default all)
hours=${2:-24}  ## login hours (default 24)
```

Which will initialize `user` to the first positional parameter (or empty if none is given) and `hours` to the second positional parameter (`24` if none is given). Both parameters are required if you wish to specify either one.

It's probably easiest to write a function to process a single record from `who` output. That way you either call it once for a single user, or call it in a loop to check all users. A simple function check the user login time could be:

```
declare -i nseconds=$((hours * 3600))   ## no. of hours in seconds

## function takes output from who and outputs time user logged in
#  if greater than hours specified
chkuserlogin() {
    read -r -a record < <(grep "^$user" < <(who))       ## read into array
    local startsecs=$(date -d "${record[2]} ${record[3]}" +'%s') ## start time
    local loginsecs=$(($(date +'%s') - startsecs))      ## login time (secs)
    if ((loginsecs >= nseconds)); then  ## if greater than nseconds, report
        printf "user: %s logged %d hours.\n" "$user" $((loginsecs / 3600))
    fi
}
```

Where the `date` function is used to convert the login time and current time to seconds since epoch, and then take the difference to get the total user login time.

Controlling whether you call `chkuserlogin()` once for a single user, or in a loop to check all users, you can do something like:

```
lastu=""        ## last user checked (empty)

if [ -n "$user" ]; then                         ## for single user
    chkuserlogin < <(grep "^$user" < <(who))
else                                            ## for all users
    while read -r -a line; do
        if [ "$lastu" != "${line[0]}" ]; then
            chkuserlogin <<< "$line"
        fi
        lastu="${line[0]}"
    done < <(who)
fi
```

Which just makes the decision on calling for a single user or all based on whether the `user` variable is empty or not.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

user="${1:-}"   ## user to check (default all)
hours=${2:-24}  ## login hours (default 24)
lastu=""        ## last user checked (empty)

declare -i nseconds=$((hours * 3600))   ## no. of hours in seconds

## function takes output from who and outputs time user logged in
#  if greater than hours specified
chkuserlogin() {
    read -r -a record < <(grep "^$user" < <(who))       ## read into array
    local startsecs=$(date -d "${record[2]} ${record[3]}" +'%s') ## start time
    local loginsecs=$(($(date +'%s') - startsecs))      ## login time (secs)
    if ((loginsecs >= nseconds)); then  ## if greater than nseconds, report
        printf "user: %s logged %d hours.\n" "$user" $((loginsecs / 3600))
    fi
}

if [ -n "$user" ]; then                         ## for single user
    chkuserlogin < <(grep "^$user" < <(who))
else                                            ## for all users
    while read -r -a line; do
        if [ "$lastu" != "${line[0]}" ]; then
            chkuserlogin <<< "$line"
        fi
        lastu="${line[0]}"
    done < <(who)
fi
```

There are always additional validations you can add like checking that `hours` entered was an integer value, etc.. (that is left to you) Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Hi thank you. I am still testing. After 24hrs who command out show "old" instead of 24hrs

Comment: The 1st script is good only it's complain about line 19 read -r -a record < <(grep "^$user" < < (who)) syntax error when I give command line argument ./user.sh Ali 18. 2nd : is it possible ./user. The output says " user longged 80 hour. " Instead it show user name . Thank you

Comment: You are supposed to give the user name as the 1st argument like `shan` and then `18`. I think it may be better to give time first and then user. If you want to check all, you just omit the `user` argument. To do that, just change `hours=${1:-24}` and `user="${2:-}"`. That way you could just enter `./nameofscript.sh 18` for all users over `18` hours, or `./nameofscript.sh 18 shan` for just user `shan`.

Comment: To not show the users name, just change `printf "user logged in %d hours.\n" $((loginsecs / 3600))`

Comment: 1st of all thank you so much . I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet shows how the login time of user 'oracle' can be calculated:

```
#!/bin/bash

# how many senconds has a day?
seconds24hour=$(( 24 * 60 * 60 ))

# read content from who into array
read -r -a content <<< "$(who | grep '^oracle')"

# convert logintime into seconds
logintime=$(date -d "${content[2]} ${content[3]}" +"%s")

# convert now into seconds
now=$(date -d now +"%s")

# compute difference
difftime=$(( now - logintime ))

if [[ $difftime > $seconds24hour ]]; then
    echo "user logged in over 24 hours"
fi
```

Comment: Hi thank you.  1st part of the script : ./user-mon.sh dba-  12(hours)  it show user dba- logged in 12 hrs.   2nd: part of script.  If I didn't give any argument 1st part don't excited and 2nd part excute and show all user who are logged in over 24hrs "old".